# copying a multidimensional array via serialization

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, deep-copy

I intend to copy a three-dimensional array via serialization, using the following class:

```
public class Serializer {

    public byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
        o.writeObject(obj);
        return b.toByteArray();
    }

    public Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);
        return o.readObject();
    }
}
```

Then, in my main code I write this:

```
int array[][][] = new int[param][][];
Serializer s = new Serializer();
byte [] b = s.serialize(array);
Object arrayCopy = s.deserialize(b);
```

However, I do get an error message on the last line: "Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException"

Also, I don't know how can I convert the Object arrayCopy to an int[param][][], which is my final objective. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: The whole Serializer Class does not actually do, what you want. An ObjectStream reads a Java Object (e.g. a String or a List for example) not a byte array. It only reads FROM a inputstream (bytearray).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I do get an error message on the last line: "Unhandled
>   exception type ClassNotFoundException"

Your `deserialize` method throws two checked exceptions (IOException, ClassNotFoundException), which have to be handled in calling code with a try-catch block.

> Also, I don't know how can I convert the Object arrayCopy to an
>   int[param][][], which is my final objective

You cast objects by prepending the RHS of the expression with the desired type (int[][][]), in brackets. Note that in your case, this is an *unsafe* cast, since you really don't know the type of object that is being returned from the `deserialize` method.

Combining both exception handling and casting, your main code should look something like this:

```
try {
    int array[][][] = new int[param][][];
    Serializer s = new Serializer();
    byte [] b = s.serialize(array);
    Object arrayCopy = (int[][][]) s.deserialize(b);
} catch(IOException ioe) {
    // ... handle this
} catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
    // ... handle this
}
```

---

### Safe(er) Casting

If you wanted to avoid the unsafe casting, you could use generics to indicate the expected return type of the `deserialize` method. You would also need to do a validation within the method itself, that the deserialized object was actually of a desired class type. Something like this:

```
public class Serializer {

    public <T> byte[] serialize(T obj) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
        o.writeObject(obj);
        return b.toByteArray();
    }

    public <T> T deserialize(Class<T> clazz, byte[] bytes) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);
        final Object raw = o.readObject();
        if (raw.getClass().isAssignableFrom(clazz))
            return clazz.cast(raw);
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Byte data does not represent a class of type " + clazz);
    }
}
```

Notice the changes to the `deserialize` method are:

- Add a (method level) generic parameter `T`
- Add an additional parameter (`Class<T>`) that represents the expected type to be returned
- Add validation in the method to confirm that the deserialized object is in fact, an instance of the desired class
- Add an illegal argument exception, in the case that the deserialized object is ***not*** in fact, an instance of the desired class

If you use these modifications, in your main code you should also handle `IllegalArgumentException`.